# Solicitud de multiples permisos. Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-permissions

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de solicitud de permisos para una app en Android Studio.
Requiero permiso de cámara y acceder a la memoria externa. Hasta los momentos lo hace. Pero tengo un método onRequestPermissionsResult, que me muestra en un Toast cuando se otorga o no un permiso, con el error de que solo me muestra el de la cámara.

```
private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA = 1001;
private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_WRITE = 1002;
private boolean permissionGranted;

 if (!permissionGranted){
        checkPermissionsCAM();
        return;
    }




// Initiate request for permissions.
private boolean checkPermissionsCAM() {
    
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    int permissionCheck1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED  ) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA);
        return false;
    } else if(permissionCheck1 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_WRITE);
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String permissions[],
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA:
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissionGranted = true;
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permiso de cámara otorgado",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Debes otorgar permiso de cámara!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_PERMISSION_WRITE:
            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                permissionGranted1 = true;
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permiso de almacenamiento externo otorgado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Debes otorgar el permiso de memoria", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Solo me falta que me funcione bien el último método.
De antemano mil gracias.

Comment: estas usando un if.. else if, por esa razón solo entra a revisar un permiso, revisa lo que comento en mi respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas definiendo que solo se revise alguno de los 2 permisos y no ambos, realiza el siguiente cambio en tu método **`checkPermissionsCAM()`** para revisar los permisos por separado.

```
// Initiate request for permissions.
private boolean checkPermissionsCAM() {
    
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    int permissionCheck1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED  ) {
          ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA);              
    } 

    if(permissionCheck1 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_WRITE);
    }

    return true;
}
```

En `onRequestPermissionsResult()` también puedes revisar los permisos realizando el siguiente cambio:

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String permissions[],
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    //switch (requestCode) {
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA || requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION_WRITE){ //case REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA:
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissionGranted = true;
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permiso de cámara otorgado",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Debes otorgar permiso de cámara!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            //break;
        //case REQUEST_PERMISSION_WRITE:
            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                permissionGranted1 = true;
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permiso de almacenamiento externo otorgado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Debes otorgar el permiso de memoria", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
           // break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Jorgesys no lo hace. Separé los if y no lo hace. No entra al segundo case del switch

Comment: Ah, espera acabo de ver que tienes return en false, revisa la actualización.

Comment: Le quité los retur false y nadahttps://es.stackoverflow.com/users/95/jorgesys

Comment: Explica que sucede, si se llama uno pero el otro no ? revisaste si ya se asigno algún permiso de la app?

Comment: Despues de instalar la app, aparece el cuadro de dialogo pidiendo los dos permisos, pero cuando se ejecuta esta acción (permitir o denegar), solo aparce un toast, que es para el primer caso de la cámara

Comment: Lo que quiere decir que no se sabe si se otorgó o no el permiso del storage

Comment: Eso lo puedes ver en la configuración de la app instalada, probablemente ya tienes uno de los permisos por eso no se llama el otro.

Comment: Viste el codigo de onRequestPermissionsResult()? está bien escrito?

Comment: Jorgesys♦ ya resolví

Comment: mira este código

Comment: gracias por tu apoyo...

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String permissions[],
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                permissionGranted = true;
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permiso de cámara otorgado",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Debes otorgar permiso de cámara!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                permissionGranted1 = true;
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permiso de Memoria otorgado",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Debes otorgar permiso de Memoria!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            break;
       
    }
}
```